# Android Studio: How do I show 2 Activities in one screen at the same time?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

So I am using a navigation drawer which is my MainActivity. When I click on one of the options it's supposed to execute an Activity which shows a list of events. The drawer menu should still be visible at the top.

At the moment it's opening the list activity on top of the MainActivity so that they're seperate and not visible at the same time as you can see in the following screenshots:

Navigation Drawer [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qil5.png)

Event list activity [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blosc.png)

This is the MainActivity shown after closing the event list activity window by hitting the back button [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7A3Z.png)

Thats my MainActivity and with the method selectDrawerItem it navigates to the different activities:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView nvDrawer;

// Make sure to be using androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle version.
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // This will display an Up icon (<-), we will replace it with hamburger later
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Find our drawer view
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

    // Setup toggle to display hamburger icon with nice animation
    drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    // Find our drawer view
    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    // Setup drawer view
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    // NOTE: Make sure you pass in a valid toolbar reference.  ActionBarDrawToggle() does not require it
    // and will not render the hamburger icon without it.
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
    FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = null;
    Intent intent = null;
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }



    // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    // Set action bar title
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    // Close the navigation drawer
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    /*// The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }*/

    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

So basically I want to open what you can see in number 2 within number 3. How do I do that? 
I already tried using fragments but it must be an activity because of how the app shall work later. So that's not an option.

(Android Beginner btw:°) )

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one activity running at once. Your case requires fragmentation.

Please see the documentation for using fragments. If you need help let me know.

Comment: I can't use fragments as the fusedlocationprovider I use with Maps doesn't work in fragments

Answer (score 0):

U can use fragments with view pager